# Window object recognition using RFT on Print Dialogue

Tags: rft

Why is RFT not recognizing the objects I have on a windows Print dialog.Included are few screen shots.

### I am able to get the correct activeWIndow by

TestObject[] to ;
IWindow activeWindow = RationalTestScript.getScreen().getActiveWindow(); 
System.out.println("Class of active window is "+activeWindow.getCLass()): // returns #32770

ScreenTestObject root = RootTestObject.getScreenTestObject();

### to = root.find(atLIst(atDescendant(".class", false),atChild(".class", ".Pushbutton", ".text", "Print"))) ;

Apparantly I can't post pictures. here is the link for print window and print button properties screenshot
http://www.flickr.com/photos/24358027@N07/12977082214/in/set-72157641973533994 
...resolutions is horrible, I can type all the information if anyone needs it. Sorry and Thanks in advance.

Comment: This print dialog origintates from which parent window  ?  I mean  does it come from IE /FF   or Notepad or some other application?  As you ahve the object map I would take that RFT is able to recognize the control during record time but not during playback what is the error thrown(if any) during playback?    .  Also the above code that you have pasted is that not working too ? or is that the resolution you are referring to ?

Comment: Print window is coming from IE, I have the code wrapped in try catch so during playback ,just the step fails with Test Object not found like warning. Above code or the solution Archiekins has posted is one of many I have tried to locate the Print button, but RFT just won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try The below Code snippet. I tried launching the print dialog from notepad and ran below script to find the print button and click it.Hope it helps.

```
//Find the Print button
TestObject[] to = find(atDescendant(".class",".Pushbutton",".text","Print"),true);
System.out.println(to.length);
//If you are sure you have just one print button on screen. 
if(to.length==1)
    ((GuiTestObject) to[0]).click();
//Else traverse through the found object and compare the properties of the button you want to click
```

Comment: Thanks Guyz. @Archiekins, Thanks for the solution, but it didn't work , At this point I am assuming it has to be a bug on the RFT installation , I have a similar window and once I have the window I am able to see all the children by activeWindow.getChildre() and act on them. This print window has similar properties as the other window and RFT is just not recognizing any children with same properties name ( different values , ofCourse) .

Answer (score 0):

Update : I did a workaround for this, using tab to navigate. Once Tab is on the button, I input Enter. So it's not a work stoppage issue anymore, but I do need to figure out the right way to do it. 
Thanks